# Using Entity Framework/LINQ, can you define a default object once and for all?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework (Code First), is there a way of defining a default object without having to do add `DefaultIfEmpty(new ....)` every time when making a query? Instead whenever you do call `FirstOrDefault()`, `LastOrDefault()`, `SingleOrDefault()` and the returned result is empty it returns the defined default object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier solution by adding an extension method to the code from functional programming.

```
using System;

namespace GetOrElse
{
    public static class GetOrElseExtension
    {
        public static T GetOrElse<T>(this Nullable<T> instance, T orElse) where T: struct
        {
            if (instance == null)
                return orElse;

            return instance.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it to shorten the amount of typing by calling (in this example, get a string value -

```
var result = YourEntity.Where(...).FirstOrDefault().GetOrElse<string>("DefaultValueHere");
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/ijoyce/1366016

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't control it - it the the default for the used datatype (null, zero for int etc.)
I usually use ?? operator in conjunction with FirstOrDefault to assign value that I want to see when it is null.